# Getting 411 Response for http GET request on cloudflare URL

Tags: http-headers, cdn, codenameone, cloudflare

Our website uses cloudflare as it's CDN to handle loads.

One of our apps requests the URL http://www.codenameone.com/files/cn1libs/CN1JSON.cn1lib with a get request. This works fine for every machine/location we tested but we have user complaints that they are getting an HTTP 411: "Length Required" response.

Since this is a GET request content-length doesn't seem like a header we would need to send...

Our server logs don't show any 411 response so my only conclusion is that this is a failure on the cloudflare side. However, since we can't reproduce this and the cloudflare aspect is a black box I don't have much to go on in terms of debugging.

I tried contacting cloudflare support but effectively got the usual "run around" asking me to send traces from a users machine on the other side of the world which is not something I can realistically do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long session with cloudflare support it seems that unless you are an enterprise subscriber log files for access just don't exist. So effectively their support sees cloudflare as a black box just like we do.

Since the problem clearly isn't in our servers my educated guess is that this is a bug in cloudflare related to some odd edge case.

If someone has a better answer than this I'll gladly accept it.